# how does a debugger start a subprocess and get register data using ptrace?

Tags: c++, fork, ptrace

The documentation of ptrace lists multiple ways the function can be called. I tried to create code to demonstrate it working, first by running a job and defining that it should be debugged using PTRACE_TRACEME

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>

using namespace std;
int main() {
  int pid = getpid();
  long status = ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, pid, nullptr, nullptr);
  sleep(6000);
  int a = 3;
  uint64_t b = 123;
  float f = 1.2;
  double d = 2.5;
  cout << a << b << f << d;
  return 0;
}
```

The code comes back from ptrace returning -1. None of the parameters means anything, and maybe the return doesn't either. Nothing is mentioned in the docs.

In order to attempt to interact with the process, I run:

gdb simpledebug

Here is the code for the debugger. I pass in the pid on the command line and attempt to attach. The return is -1
which I assume is failure.

```
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  uint32_t pid = atoi(argv[1]);

  long status  = ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pid, nullptr, nullptr);
  cout << "attaching to task " << pid << " status=" << status << '\n';
  struct iovec iov_intregs;
  status = ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, nullptr, &iov_intregs); // get the integer registers
  cout << "status=" << status << " int regs: " << iov_intregs.iov_base << " len=" << iov_intregs.iov_len << '\n';
  struct iovec iov_fpregs;
  ptrace(PTRACE_GETFPREGS, pid, nullptr, &iov_fpregs); // get the fp registers
  cout << "status=" << status << " fp regs: " << iov_fpregs.iov_base << " len=" << iov_fpregs.iov_len << '\n';
}
```

So first, can anyone explain what is going wrong? Second, can someone show me how to fork off and execute the process? Because as I understand it, the child task would have to execute PTRACE_TRACEME, but the documentation mentions options like PTRACE_O_TRACEFORK that I don't really fully understand.

If it debugee really does have to call PTRACE_TRACEME, then a debugger must first call its own process, execute that call, then exec the debug process, right? In any case, I can't even get through the first call.

I would like to create the first few lines of a simple debugger demo. Once the connection is established, the ability to get the registers (which is in this demo) and get memory (peek) seems fairly obvious.

I was kind of startled that the only way to examine memory is 64 bits at a time though. Is there no simpler way to map the task memory so it can be explored faster? Is there a reason why the debugger does not want to map in the task of the debuggee as shared memory, readonly?

Comment: This might be useful: https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/writing-a-linux-debugger-setup/

Comment: Your first block of code works OK for me on Debian bullseye; `ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, ...)` returns 0. What OS, kernel version and distro are you using? There may be some kernel variables that need to be changed to relax security so that ptrace can work.

Comment: ubuntu 20.04.

I also wanted to try it on msys2 under windows, but I didn't want to start there because of the potential minefield of compatability issues. gdb works on both platforms, and I assume it is using ptrace?

Comment: What number (0, 1, 2, etc.) is output by `sysctl kernel.yama.ptrace_scope` on your Ubuntu system?`